# gitflow-maven-plugin with protected master branch: create PR

Tags: maven, github, git-flow

My `master` branch at github is protected, changes can only be made via Pull-Requests. With gitflow-maven-plugin `gitflow:release` I'd like to create a PR from `develop` to `master` instead of a push to `master`.

As far as I understand I could use `<gitPushOptions>`. Current configuration is:

`<gitPushOptions>merge_request.create merge_request.target=master</gitPushOptions>`

But I still get:

`Failed to execute goal com.amashchenko.maven.plugin:gitflow-maven-plugin:1.18.0:release  on project ***: release: remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/master.`

Seems like I am missing something.

Comment: I haven't used this tool, but my guess is that the pushOptions is stuff you do along with a push. You can't push to `master` because it's protected, so maybe you would need to push to some other branch (any branch?) and have it create a PR to `master`. That feels a little clunky though. My preference would probably be to allow one specific automation user to be able to push directly to `master` without a PR. Git Flow merges from `release` (or `develop` if you skip using a `release` branch) to `master` can't possibly have conflicts, so automation is simple and there's no code review necessary.